# How to set figure size or plot size in a Gadfly plot (using Julia)?

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly

I would like to set the width (and height) of my `Gadfly` plot to adjust the aspect ratio in a `hstack` plot.

Orginal plot:

```
using Gadfly
p1 = Gadfly.plot(x=[1,2], y=[3,4], Geom.line)
```

[image]

`hstack` plot (to be adjusted):

```
using Gadfly
p1 = Gadfly.plot(x=[1,2], y=[3,4], Geom.line)
hstack(p1, p1, p1)
```

[image]

Any suggestions on how to adjust the plot size / figure size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the [Gadfly galleries](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/gallery/geometries/), plots use `set_default_plot_size()`.  Another option is e.g.:

```
p = plot(...)
draw(PNG(6inch, 3inch), p)
```

see `?SVG`, `?PDF`, `?PNG` for more info.